# react-checkbox-tree does not keep color on nodes

Tags: reactjs, checkboxtree

Guys.
I am recently using react-checkbox-tree.
I would like to keep color stay on nodes when I hover or click the nodes. (background color)
I see the color when I hover them, but when I click other buttons or move mouse away,
the color is gone.
Is there any method I can make the color stay?